# Does Firebase A/B testing work with Amazon Fire TV or kindle fire?

Tags: firebase, amazon-fire-tv, firebase-ab-testing

Is Firebase A/B testing compatible with Amazon Fire TV?

I use crashlytics with fire tv.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase A/B testing uses Remote Config and FCM, both of which require Google Play services. Play services isn't available on Fire TVs as far as I know, so A/B testing is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is however
microg vanced (google play alternative)
Was able to sign in with YouTube vanced app
& YouTube music (microg vanced mod)
Directly on the fire tv

Not sure if firebase is supported with it though